# What do we call a sequence that converges in finite steps?

Tags: convergence-divergence, terminology

What do we call a sequence that converges in finite steps?

E.g. $3,2,1,0,0,0\ldots$

as opposed to $\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{4},\frac{1}{8},\frac{1}{16},$

I know we would call either convergent.  But is there a stronger name for the first case?  I searched for it and can't find a name.  The best terminology I can come up with is to say that it becomes constant.

Comment: I would say 'it stabilizes'.

Comment: Maybe a "stationary" sequence ?

Comment: also: "eventually constant"  -- and if you want to be fancy: "convergent under the discrete topology"

Comment: A sequence whose generating function is a polynomial.

Comment: "Eventually constant" is quite common.

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen Since you got here first, would you mind making that comment an answer so this no longer appears unanswered?